# Big endian or little endian?

Tags: byte-order

I need to pass a 16-bit long address (for an external EEPROM) to a function (`twi_writeTo`) in a buffer.
I am currently doing this

```
byte buffer[2];
buffer[0] = (byte)(eeaddress >> 8);
buffer[1] = (byte)(eeaddress & 0xFF);
```

where `eeaddress` is an `unsigned int` with the address.

I then do

```
int8_t ret = twi_writeTo(eeprom_i2c_addr, buffer, 2, 1);
```

Before I tried

```
int8_t ret = twi_writeTo(eeprom_i2c_addr, (uint8_t*)&eeaddress, 2, 1);
```

but that returns garbage. Probably the byte order is swapped. Is that the case?
And if so, is there a better way than copying the two bytes to a buffer?

Comment: If you think endianness is the problem, just change `buffer[0]` to `buffer[1]` and vice versa, and check if that fixes your problem.

Comment: The use of `(uint8_t*)&eeaddress` and `buffer` is mutually exclusive, so I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Swap the `buffer[]` bytes over and see if that creates the same garbage that `(uint8_t*)&eeaddress` does.  If so, then yes it is an endian problem.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by `it returns garbage`? Please give some examples with hex numbers.

Comment: Garbage as in it reads "arbitrary" addresses so that the result doesn't make sense. I checked and indeed the first approach swaps the bytes w.r.t. the second. So, yes, it's the byte order.

Answer (score 2):

If it's the byte order that causes a problem that's likely compiler specific and I don't think one can change it. Even if it were possible, changing the global endianness might break libraries that depend on it, so you likely can't escape using a function to swap the variable.

If you know you only need one value at a time you could write something like the following code, with a global buffer (untested but in principle should work (and I know global variables are evil, but should work for an Arduino project)):

```
byte buf[2];

byte* reverse(int val) {
    buf[0] = (byte)(val >> 8);
    but[1] = (byte)val;
    return buf;
}
```

So you could use it like:

```
int8_t ret = twi_writeTo(eeprom_i2c_addr, reverse(eeaddress), 2, 1);
```